# requests не работает с HTTPS

Tags: python-3.x, requests

```
text = requests.get('https://belgorod.hh.ru/account/login').text
```

в ответ приходит 404 ошибка.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В том, что сайт заблокировал использование `requests`

Comment: Раз ответ приходит, значит requests работает с https.

Comment: Потому что в вас увидели робота

Answer (score 0):

**Не забываем про заголовки**

```
import requests


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2)\
    AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)\
    Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'
    }

url = 'https://belgorod.hh.ru/account/login'

page = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text

print(page)
```

**Альтернатива**

```
from grab import Grab

g = Grab()

g.go("https://belgorod.hh.ru/account/login")
g.set_input('username', 'Ваш логин')
g.set_input('password', 'Ваш пароль')
g.submit()


g.go('И здесь url интересующей вас страницы')
print(g.xpath_text('//title'))
```

Comment: @Алекнсандр зачем вы для авторизации используете другую библиотеку? это можно сделать средствами requests

Comment: там на форме не `Login` и `Password`, а `username` и `password`. Да и для requests можно сделать POST запрос с form-encoded данными, либо попробовать через Basic Auth: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication

Comment: gil9red danilshik спасибо поправил!